# How would the total charge density of n-type semiconductor formula change after applying bias?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

The following formula is the total charge density of n-type semiconductor. When we apply, let's say, 2 V bias to this semiconductor, how would this formula change?

$$\rho=N_C\frac1{\operatorname{exp}\left[\dfrac{(E_C-E_F)}{kT}\right]+1}+N_D\left[1-\dfrac1{\operatorname{exp}\left[\dfrac{(E_D-E_F)}{kT}\right]+1}\right]$$

($N_C$: effective density of states in conduction band; $N_D$: n-type donor concentration; $E_C$: bottom of the conduction band energy; $E_F$: Fermi energy level; $E_D$: Donor ionization energy; $k$: Boltzmann constant; $T$: temperature)

Comment: It's highly appreciated if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to present formulae, rather than graphics files.

Comment: Why do you think the charge density will change?

Comment: How do you envision applying a bias? Do you propose to take a chunk of Si, hook up to leads to it, and apply 2V across the leads?